# How can I label velodyen points in Kitti dataset point per point?

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, point-clouds

I am trying to train my neutral network using velodyen points in kitti dataset. The dataset has around 450 frame as bin file . Each frame has around 120k row of x,y,z,re as shown below:

[image]

However, I want to add another column that has the labels for each point .

Any thought how I can handle this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The KITTI Vision Benchmark Suite does not provide per-point labels so if you want that information you would have to manually annotate it or find other dataset to work with (like: http://www.semantic3d.net/).

I guess that you could use the 3D bounding box information (http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_object.php?obj_benchmark=3d) to label all the points inside the bounding box with the corresponding class, but you will still have missing per-point labels for the rest of the scene. So maybe kitti is not the right dataset for what you are trying to do (use per-point labels)

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I know that we can label the points inside the 3d bounding box , but this is not helping as my network classify point per point as well as my application is for self-driving car ,so I don't thing semantic3d dataset would fit my network . 
I really appropriate your reply